# Reactjs. Fetch data from server and connect it to i18n

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I cannot understand how to integrate dynamic content in array to i18n.

Let's say, server returns some data, an array of todo objects:

```
const todos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    isChecked: true,
    i18n: [
      { id: 1, languageId: 1, title: "Take a nap" },
      { id: 2, languageId: 2, title: "Zdrzemnąć się" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    isChecked: false,
    i18n: [
      { id: 3, languageId: 1, title: "Make dinner" },
      { id: 4, languageId: 2, title: "Zrobić obiad" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Each todo object already has all translation data so it's **not** in JSON file.

Now in my `render()` function, I render my todos and I want to show the `title` of each todo by using *i18next* framework.

Is it possible to achieve this with the power of `i18n`? (react-i18next) 
Maybe there are some examples in official documentation? I'm not sure I can figure this out on my own.

Comment: If the server returns all translations, why bother using a library? You can very well create a custom util of your own.

Comment: I could, but let's say my project is already using the `i18n` to manage all static content. So I'm thinking... wouldn't it be better if everything is managed from one place (one library)? Isn't it a better approach?

Comment: I don't know that I understand your example.  Your 2 tasks have 2 different `id`s and seem to be in 2 different languages.  However, they have the same `languageId`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing out. Yes, it was a mistake with `languageId`. I've updated the code.

Comment: So each `todo task` has its `i18n` array with *objects*. And each *object* in it has data about language id and title.

Comment: i18next works with keys & values per language, you can group your data by language, add the keys, and use `i18next.addResourceBundle` into "special" namespace, lets say **dynamic**, then use the namespace & the proper keys in your React component

Comment: Thank you. Can you please confirm if the approach of using i18n in this situation is appropriate? As is was mentioned earlier by @technophyle to implement custom util. 

Would it be efficient to use `i18next.addResourceBundle` if there are lots of todos? Consider 80 todos with 3 languages, it will trigger the `addResourceBundle` 240 times.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation and thanks to @technophyle I'll use my own util.

Here's the quick code example:

```
const template = { title: '' };

get text() {
    const text = todos.find(t =>
        t.languageId === App.Lang.id;

    if (!text)
        return template;
    return { ...template, ...text };
 }
```

The proposed use of `i18next.addResourceBundle` seems a bit overwhelmed to me, as it required to do a lot of parsing with arrays.

But in general, I think this is not the way it should be done if a project already using `i18n` to manage the static transactions. `i18n` has some cool functionality, like, detecting default language, in my case, I wouldn't be able to use it and I would need to maintain two different translation systems on my project: the `i18n` and my own util for handling dynamic translation.